# Passing variables to setActiveItem

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How do i pass variables with Sencha Touch 2's setactiveitem function.

What I had was (which were working) instead of using setactiveitem i was using pop and push

```
var main = this.getMain();
    main.pop();
    main.push({
        xtype: 'carddetails',
        card: card,
        title: card.get('name'),
    });
```

But I switched to panel with layout card and as I activate the view I want to pass some variables:

```
main.setActiveItem('#carddetails',card); //something like this
```

How can i pass variables in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, just create a function like `updateViewWithData(data)` where you update your view before showing it.

By the way, you weren't passing data to your `push()` function before, you were creating a view by passing a config object (which you don't do anymore with your `setActiveItem()`).

Comment: thanks for the explanation! any suggestions how i can update my view?

Comment: Update your post with the code of your view and tell us what you want to do.